# Return multiple data with condition from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having problem with fetching data from multiple tables with some conditions in MySQL.

I have follwing three tables:

```
   Like Table

   Like_id  photoID  userID
         1        1       1
         2        2       2
         3        2       1


   BookMark Table

   bookmark_id  photoID  userID
             1        1       1
             2        2       2
             3        2       1


   Users Table

   User_id  Name       Email
         1  Max B      maxb@gmailcom
         2  Tom Smith  toms@gmailcom
```

**CONDITIONS:**

At first i want to check whether there is any data from the LIKE table for the userID = 2. If there is no data it should return "false" otherwise it should return "true".

Similarly, i want to check whether there is any data from the BOOKMARK table for the userID = 2. If there is no data it should return "false" otherwise it should return "true".

Finally, i want to fetch the Name and Email from the USERS table for the userID = 2.

**WANTED:**

I want to achieve all these information in a **SINGLE QUERY** with the above mentioned conditions from these three tables.

SO FAR tried with this QUERY:

```
   select Like.Like_id from (Like left join Users on Like.userID = Users.User_id) 
   left join BookMark on Users.User_id = BookMark.bookmark_id 
   where Users.User_id = 2
```

With @Gervs suggestion:

```
SELECT
u.user_id,
u.name,
u.email,
(CASE WHEN ISNULL(l.user_id) THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END) AS 'likes',
(CASE WHEN ISNULL(b.user_id) THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END) AS 'bookmarks'
FROM 
 users u
LEFT JOIN
  likes l
  ON u.user_id = l.user_id
LEFT JOIN
 bookmarks
 ON u.user_id = b.user_id
 WHERE u.user_id = 2
 GROUP BY u.user_id
```

What will be the easiest but efficient single query to fetch these information?
Will VIEW be a best option for these conditions?

Advanced thanks for your participation.

Comment: Yes, this can be done in one query.  The easiest way will be to `LEFT JOIN` **Users** to both **Like** and **Bookmark** and interpret `NULL` as false.

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks. Can you please write in mysql query?

Comment: Why wouldn't at least *try* to do it yourself?

Comment: @PM77-1 I have tried this: select Like.Like_id from (Like left join Users on Like.userID = Users.User_id) 
left join BookMark on Users.User_id = BookMark.bookmark_id

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to put code in comments. Add it (Edit) to your post instead.

Comment: @PM77-1 have you seen my added queries? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Gervs gave a good answer. If instead of counts you really want to produce true or false, you can wrap 'em in `CASE` structure.

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks. can you please give me updated query with CASE structure?

Comment: Are your "*true*" and "*false*" strings?

Comment: yes. it will be strings

Comment: `CASE WHEN (count expression) > 0 THEN "true" ELSE "false" END`

Comment: thanks . if possible please show me the complete query.

Comment: I purposely didn't post a full answer. You need to exert yourself.

Comment: @PM77-1 i have updated the query with CASE. is it correct now?

Comment: Gervs apparently feels generous today, so s/he posted your entire query. If you do not have access to MySQL server, you can create [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and run queries on-line. It has very nice **Text to DDL** feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inner join both like table and bookmark table on users table, that is if you want only users that have entries in both tables.

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.name,
    u.email,
    COUNT(l.user_id) likes,
    COUNT(b.user_id) bookmarks
FROM 
    users u
JOIN
    likes l
    ON u.user_id = l.user_id
JOIN
   bookmarks b
    ON u.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = 2
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

If you always want the user, just change the inner joins into left joins and likes and/or bookmarks will be zero if no entries are found

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.name,
    u.email,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(l.user_id) > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END likes,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(b.user_id) > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END bookmarks
FROM 
    users u
LEFT JOIN
    likes l
    ON u.user_id = l.user_id
LEFT JOIN
    bookmarks b
    ON u.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = 2
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Comment: thanks. Are you saying something similar that i have written in the edited post?

Comment: No, there is a big difference which table is on the left side of the left join

Comment: Gervs ..many thanks for your help. If you look at the updated query, you can see I have already edited the query and tested. It runs perfectly as I wanted. Thanks for both of you and @PM77-1 help. 
Also will this question answer help others? Have a great day. cheers